# How to turn on proximity sensor on Samsung S10 phones

Tags: android, sip, samsung-mobile, proximity

I'm developing app for wi/fi calling.

I want to turn off screen when proximity sensor reports "near". It work fine on other phones but on S10 phone looks like proximity sensor is not even activated - there is no white dot blinking on top part of the screen.

If I make normal call or use WhatsApp dot starts blinking as soon as I start the call.

So what do I have to do to make that white dot blink on Samsung S10 phone?